# When Dates of Contract End Date Pass, Contract Status Should Expire

Tags: field-update, workflowrule, criteria

I have created Workflow rule and selected criteria as like below and after pick list field update selected Expired.

```
ahm__Contract_Expiration_Date__c < TODAY( )
```

But when I select the dates less than today then automatically it used to change the picklist value to Expired but if I put the same date like today and check in tomorrow then I find it does not change picklist value to Expired. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Standard workflow fires on field changes, meaning that your rule won't be automatically evaluated at night when TODAY() changes. Instead, try using a time based workflow action to perform your update. These are automatically evaluated based on date criteria.

Answer (score 0):

If your workflow field update is running as **immediate action**, then it will run only when the record is created / updated and the criteria matches.

what you need is to make the field update as a **time based or scheduled action** and set it to run after X hours (choose your own time) the Contract Expiration Date..

then the system will queue your field update action and run it once the contract date expires (you might need to adjust your criteria on create / edit so the action gets into the queue)

Comment: Rule Criteria ahm__Contract_Expiration_Date__c < TODAY( )
Evaluation Criteria Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria
Immediate Workflow Actions
Field Update Contract Status Expire
So its immediate workflow action already I have added so why it is not working as expected. Do I need to put if the criteria met then after one hour field get an update?